# I can't calculate Liquidity of a pair using getReserves() function

Tags: web3.py

I've been trying for days to get the liquidity of a pair using getReserves() function

Examples :
1/ https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82
--> liquidity of BNB / CAKE pair is 368,167.50 BNB

[image]

2/ https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xf73d8276c15ce56b2f4aee5920e62f767a7f3aea
--> liquidity of TCG2 / CAKE pair is 4,466.91 BNB

[image]

My code is :

```
def check_pool(inToken, outToken, symbol):
pair_address = factoryContract.functions.getPair(inToken, outToken).call()
DECIMALS = decimals(outToken)

pair_contract = client.eth.contract(address=pair_address, abi=lpAbi)
reserves = pair_contract.functions.getReserves().call()
pooled = max(reserves[0], reserves[1]) / DECIMALS
    
return pooled
```

I tried with reserves[0] or reserves[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0zHs.png), but I don't understand which one to use...
The problem seems to be that you can add lp like this : cake/bnb but also like this : bnb/cake...

Do you have any idea guys ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT : more details

You may understand better with an example. I added some print in the code to help me analyse:

```
def check_pool(inToken, outToken, symbol):
    # This function is made to calculate Liquidity of a token
    pair_address = factoryContract.functions.getPair(inToken, outToken).call()
    DECIMALSout = decimals(outToken)
    DECIMALSin = decimals(inToken)

    pair_contract = client.eth.contract(address=pair_address, abi=lpAbi)
    reserves = pair_contract.functions.getReserves().call()
    pooledout = reserves[1] / DECIMALSout
    pooledin = reserves[0] / DECIMALSin

    print("- inToken:", inToken)
    print("- outToken:", outToken)
    print("- reserves[0]:", pooledin)
    print("- reserves[1]:", pooledout)
    sleep(20)
```

---

---

TOKEN 1 : 0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82

This will return :

- inToken: 0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82
- outToken: 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
- reserves[0]: 16028345.985314028
- reserves[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0zHs.png): 340516.1956866685

==> liquidity that I'm looking for is in "reserves[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0zHs.png)"

---

---

TOKEN 2 : 0xf2e00684457de1a3c87361bc4bfe2de92342306c

This will return :

- inToken: 0xf2E00684457de1a3C87361bC4BfE2DE92342306C
- outToken: 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
- reserves[0]: 1183.5707810899844
- reserves[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0zHs.png): 67006291803.481026

==> liquidity that I'm looking for is in "reserves[0]"

I don't get why it's sometimes in the 0, or in the 1...

:(

Comment: Please help me guys :'(

Comment: The result of the one with the larger contract address is in reserve0.
Seems contrary to what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution myself...

Tokens are **ordered by the token contract address**
The token contract address can be interpreted as a number, and the smallest one will be token0 internally

Code:

```
def check_pool(inToken, outToken, symbol):
    # This function is made to calculate Liquidity of a token
    pair_address = factoryContract.functions.getPair(inToken, outToken).call()
    DECIMALS = decimals(outToken)
    pair_contract = client.eth.contract(address=pair_address, abi=lpAbi)
    reserves = pair_contract.functions.getReserves().call()

    # Tokens are ordered by the token contract address
    # The token contract address can be interpreted as a number
    # And the smallest one will be token0 internally
    
    ctnb1 = int(inToken, 16)
    ctnb2 = int(outToken, 16)

    if (ctnb1 > ctnb2):
        # print("reserves[0] is for token 0:")
        pooled = reserves[0] / DECIMALS
    else:
        # print("reserves[0] is for token 1:")
        pooled = reserves[1] / DECIMALS

    return pooled
```

Comment: "Tokens are ordered by the token contract address The token contract address can be interpreted as a number, and the smallest one will be token0 internally" does that mean we can compare token contract strings with comparator operators?

Comment: yes, just look at my code

Comment: Correct, to simplify my code I like to test the the addresses of the pair's tokens against the target liquidity token to determine the order. Likely if you have to do calculations based off your data you'll need to do the same.